# jquery iviewer, remove span on top?

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery iviewer plug-in, works great.  I love it.

But it puts in this span on top of the iviewer and I am having trouble getting ride of it??

http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/

```
                  initCallback: function ()
               {
                   var object = this;
                   $("#in").click(function(){ object.zoom_by(1);}); 
                   $("#out").click(function(){ object.zoom_by(-1);}); 
                   $("#fit").click(function(){ object.fit();}); 
                   $("#orig").click(function(){  object.set_zoom(100); }); 
                   $("#update").click(function(){ object.update_container_info();});
               },
```

i am pretty sure this is where is it coming from, but when i remove this, the  is still there??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this span is hard-coded
Link you provided is example, if you try to implement it, there is no span

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mareksebera/Mk2u6/

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source of the page you provided.  That  is hard coded in your HTML.  There are no references to those IDs in the plugin code.

```
<body> 
    <h1>JQuery.iviewer test</h1> 
    <!-- wrapper div is needed for opera because it shows scroll bars for reason --> 
    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <span> 
            <a id="in" href="#">+</a> 
            <a id="out" href="#">-</a> 
            <a id="fit" href="#">fit</a> 
            <a id="orig" href="#">orig</a> 
            <a id="update" href="#">update</a> 
        </span> 
        <div id="viewer" class="viewer"></div> 
        <br /> 
        <div id="viewer2" class="viewer"></div> 
        <br /> 
        <p><a href="#" id="chimg">Change Image</a></p> 
    </div> 
</body>
```